# Removing odd numbers from an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to remove odd numbers from an array, but I'm not allowed to create a new array to store the new values.

So, if I have `arr[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`
then I need it to be `arr[2,4,6,8]` so that `arr[0]` will be 2 and not 1.

I can't seem to be able to drop the even numbers without creating a new array to store the values and then feed it back into the original array with the new values.

I have tried to make `arr[i] = 0` if its an odd number but then I wasn't able to drop the 0 and replace it with the next even number.

So far, I have this:

```
void removeOdd(int arr[], int& arrSize){
    int i, j = 0;
    int temp;
    int newArrSize;
    for(i = 0, newArrSize = arrSize; i < arrSize; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 != 0){
            arr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    arrSize = newArrSize;
}
```

Comment: Side note: prefer `int newArrSize;` over `for(i = 0, newArrSize = arrSize;...`. You'll have fewer people looking at you funny. Note that this won't work any better since nothing changes `newArrSize` after it has been set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Moves all even numbers into the beginning of the array in their original order
int removeOdd(int arr[], int arrSize) {
    int curr = 0; // keep track of current position to insert next even number into
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            arr[curr++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return curr;
}

int main() {
    int arr[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    int newSize = removeOdd(arr, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i) {
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

> 0 2 4 6 8

You might want to use `std::vector`:

```
void removeOdd(std::vector<int>& arr) {
    int curr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)arr.size(); ++i) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            arr[curr++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr.resize(curr);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> arr = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
    removeOdd(arr);
    for (int number : arr) {
        std::cout << number << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: i asked if i could use vector and we aren't allowed too :/

Comment: @Knarz so, i provided two options. In case of array you need to return new size.

Comment: Yes, thank you! it ended up working with the first option! just moved the evens to the front!

Answer (score 4):

Normally (unless this is homework of some sort), you should use the algorithms in the `<algorithm>` header.

Using [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with `std::vector`'s `erase` member function, you will accomplish exactly what you want with less code:

```
std::vector<int> vec{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10 };
vec.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), [](auto const& i) {
    return i % 2 != 0;
}), std::end(vec));
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cfcbd1989def41ea)</kbd>